# Reverse engineering a semi-transparent image

Tags: gimp

I want to match the appearance of an image that is partly transparent.  The problem is that I cannot obtain the original image.  I can only obtain screenshots of it against different backgrounds.

Using images of it against black and white backgrounds, is there a way to derive the original image?  Ideally, I'd like to derive the non-transparent version of it, along with its transparency level.  I want to edit it, then re-apply the transparency.

[image]

I'm working with GIMP 2.6 on Linux, but I could obtain other software as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`Colors>Color to alpha` and remove the white (if you think the original background is white). Don't forget to add an alpha channel if necessary

The "contract" of `color-to-alpha` is that stacking the final image over a layer filled with the removed color will give the starting image. And C2A will always shoot for maximum transparency: over a white background,  a grey could be a totally opaque grey or a partially opaque black: Gimp will produce the partially opaque black.